# How to format within a large Excel column?

Tags: excel, formatting

I have an Excel spreadsheet [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?a1fu6pl0i69c84n).

What I dont know is 
if you look at the main grid the columns are formatted for space so that the description is larger. Now the part at the bottom left. I really want those 4 columns

> 'RESIDENT NAME'   'ACCOUNT NUMBER'    'DATE'  'AMOUNT DUE'

I really want them aligned with the rest of the grid but how do i subdivide the large Description column to accomodate this?

Comment: Booksman, I looked at your spreadsheet, but don't really get what it is that you want to achieve. Help me a bit here. I tried to put an image of the spreadsheet in here to make the discussion easier, but Jeff and Joel don't trust me enough to do that....... Regards, Robert Ilbrink

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of your formatting in your question I can't be sure what you want, but if you're trying to line up more than one column with the Description column, just make the Description column a merge of more than one column, then multiple columns will be able to fit underneath it.

You can merge cells by selecting them, then going to Format Cells->Alignment and clicking the `Merge cells` box.